# Is 'armeabi' 32bit or 64bit?

Tags: android, arm, 64-bit, apk, apportable

In regard to [this article](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/12/improving-app-security-and-performance.html)

There is a similar thread here, that says you can unzip the apk file and check the lib folder(if it exists), and all the architectures that are in the lib folder are supported by your apk.
The thread I am refering to is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30348216/how-to-find-if-apk-is-32-bit-or-64-bit)

The sdk we are using (apportable) outputs an apk with just the 'armeabi' folder in the lib folder. In 2019, all new applications and updates will have to have an apk that supports 64bit.

I am just wondering what does armeabi mean, is it just 32bit support or am I safe and it also supports 64bit?

There is some info about the different architectures in [this post](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis.html) but I wanted to make sure that I am not missing something.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`armeabi` is a 32bit arch which does not support floating point operations, not safe for multi-thread operations and generally not used on multi-cpu devices.

Which means, it is safe to say 99% of phones in today's market do not run on armeabi unless you have initial android phones lying around.

`armeabi-v7a` is the modern arch which supports floating point operations, multi- threading safe is used on multi-cpu devices. It is also 32-bit.

`arm64-v8a` is 64-bit arch

Note: it seems, `armeabi` is deprecated in NDK r16 and will be removed completely on r17.

**Update:** 64-bit arch support is mandatory from August 1, 2019 to publish app in play store.

Comment: Where did you get this information from? I don't find any 'official' docs.

Comment: @FiliusPatris https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/64-bit

Comment: would an android apk reporting arm64-v8a
work on a phone which is ro.product.cpu.abi armeabi-v7a ?

Answer (score 2):

For the ARM architecture, the 32-bit libraries are located in armeabi-v7a. The 64-bit equivalent is arm64-v8a.

For the x86 architecture, look for x86 for 32-bit and x86_64 for 64-bit.

https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/64-bit