# How to know if my android app supports 64bit?

Tags: java, android

Recent changes in android architecture have enforced all developers to make their android applications support 64bit.

I have gone through the [documentations](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/64-bit). But as it shows there to look for a "lib" folder that may supposedly have ".so" files.

I tried the same thing, but apparently I can't find and "lib" folder to begin with!

I have also attached a snippet of my apk-analyzer as shown in the image link https://i.stack.imgur.com/pTZTq.jpg

Can anyone suggest me what can be done or how can I ensure my apps are 64bit supported.

Comment: if you don't use native libraries, then it supports. If you use them - you have to check if they have 64 versions

Comment: If you didn't find any .so file that means you do not need to generate apk for 64bit

Comment: I also don't have lib folder. Can you please share me how you solved this problem

Comment: Check this out https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/64-bit

Comment: Did you solve this? I am unable to get the .so files and for 64 bit. I have added the required abiFilters in Gradle. Any directions?

Answer (score 4):

[image: Steps to find the apk needs to generate for 64 bit]
[Reference : Steps to find the apk needs to generate for 64 bit](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/64-bit)

Comment: please read my issue carefully. I have already been through the steps mentioned in your reference link. After "Analyze APK", I cannot find any 'lib' folder. Here is a link to my screenshot https://imgur.com/a/L7qtLGc.

Does this mean I am good to go?

Comment: If you don't see a `lib` folder, your app doesn't have any native libraries. Should you have a lib folder, you need to check that you've got 64-bit equivalents for every 32-bit you use.

Answer (score 0):

Just Generate a Apk and Use

```
Build->Analyse Apk
```

to open the Apk.
In that Under lib folder check for these below files:

```
lib/arm64-v8a
lib/x86_64
```

If they are available them the application supports 64 bit.
For more refer this URL [64Bit](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/64-bit)

Comment: that was was original question. Here is the link to the screenshot too https://imgur.com/a/L7qtLGc . can't seem to find any "lib" folder.

Answer (score 0):

From [Get your apps ready for the 64-bit requirement](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/01/get-your-apps-ready-for-64-bit.html):

> Blockquote Inspect your APK or app bundle for native code. You can check for .so files using APK Analyzer. Identify whether they are built from your own code or are imported by an SDK or library that you are using. If you do not have any .so files in your APK, you are already 64-bit compliant.

As Vladyslav Matviienko has pointed out, if you're not using native libraries, you won't see any .so file (nor lib folder) in your APK analysis, so your app is 64bit compliant.